# Regenerating a table server-side and trying to update it client-side using an Asp UpdatePanel. Client side not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, server-side

Currently I'm working on a task that involves modifying an existing table that's generated at runtime.

I moved the table to within an Asp UpdatePanel. When my server-side code is hit to filter the table, I regenerate the table rows with data that meets the current search string, and then attempt to push those changes to client-side using the Update method on the UpdatePanel the table is encapsulated in.

However, nothing on the client side appears to be getting updated. I'm definitely hitting my Update call, there's no errors, and I have ChildrenAsTriggers set to false.

The table is generated and rendered successfully during the initial page load, but post-load attempts at updating the table and re-rendering yield nothing.

Thoughts?

(names changed to protect context)

Client-side code:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="managerProxy" runat="server">
<AjaxSettings>
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="myTable" />
</AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="myTable" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" />
```